# Is it possible to let the active virtual term be the only one with audio access?

Tags: linux, fedora, audio, alsa, multiseat

I'm currently running Fedora 22 and want a setup where Kodi runs on vterm1 while steam runs on vterm2. I have set up two seats using LightDM. I am currently using ALSA in order to let Kodi bitstream HD-audio formats.

Is it possible to let the active (the one which is displayed) virtual term be the one term with audio access?

Comment: To my knowledge sound is not bound to a terminal. The only I can think of achieving what you want is through Pulseaudio, disabling sound application-wise. Now the trick is to determine what terminal is active at runtime.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to run a script when I change X display? If it is possible a solution could be to pause Kodi when changing to Steam and change pulseaudio output when changing from Steam to Kodi.

**EDIT:** I also think I know how to solve it in another way. I'm thinking of running Kodi on the internal GPU and Steam + PulseAudio on my AMD R9 270x. As I have a home theatre receiver with multiple HDMI-inputs, I think it would be a viable solution. This way I'm able to watch movies even though I have some games downloading

Comment: No, I unfortunately don't know how to run a script when X display changes. Do you also mean you're going to use 2 video connections between your computer and the video receiver? Not that it's not going to work (I have never tried permanently) but I would expect ground loops and a great deal of noise... But if it works, good to know.

Comment: Now it seems that my 270x HDMI audio output is working. Recently tried to update to the latest Fedora 22 kernel (Linux kernel 4.0.5). My current problem is that the Steam big picture mode hogs the audio output if it's running.